# How to make F-Droid hide data about incompatible packages?

Tags: linux, f-droid, motorola-droid-pro

In 2019 with F-Droid *v1.22* running on an ancient [DROID Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droid_Pro) about 95% of the much newer software is incompatible and grayed out.  When browsing by category, these grayed out apps consume most of the screen.  On this hardware F-Droid would be much more usable if there were some setting that would just hide all those grayed out apps.

Can F-Droid hide data about incompatible packages?

Failing that, is there some Linux-based app that can browse an F-Droid repository and filter out incompatible cruft?

---

DROID Pro version number data:  System version: *4.7.3.XT610.Verizon.en.US*, Android version: *2.3.4*

Comment: Have you checked with the options page? It has a toggle for that. What you describe sounds like you have "show incompatible apps" enabled, which makes F-Droid show them but grayed out (idea is to allow you browsing them all while making clear what you can install on that device and what not). Switching that toggle off should make those gray ones disappear. Please try and let me know, so I can write up an answer.

Comment: @Izzy, I have checked before.  Unfortunately, although that *"Include incompatible"* checkbox would appear to be just the thing, it's never had any noticeable effect.

Comment: In this case, rather check with the [fdroidclient issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/issues/?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=incompatible). Uh, looks like [this one](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/issues/41) is yours…

Comment: @Izzy, That 's a Bingo.  Please post that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this should be what the corresponding toggle on the Option page is for: If you untick "include incompatible apps", they should be hidden (and if you tick it, they are shown but grayed out – just as you describe).

As this doesn't work for you, you might be plagued by a [long-standing bug](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/issues/41). Unfortunately, there's nothing we at Android.SE can do about it but suggesting you to chime in there and rise awareness, so it might finally get fixed. As the issue is still open, it seems so is the bug – though updating to a more recent version is worth trying (v1.2.2 is not quite up-to-date; ATM v1.6 should be the current stable) if your Android version permits.